# Rowwise subtract vectors using purrr

Tags: r, purrr

I have a numeric dataframe (`m rows * n columns`)

For each row of this dataframe, I want to treat it as
a numeric vector (`1 * n`) and subtract from it another
**fixed** (`1 * n`) vector. So for each row we return a
(`1 * n`) vector.

I would like to **return a list** with this **vector subtraction**
done **for each row** of the dataframe. So in this case
a list with `m` number of `1 * n` vectors.

I have manually done this for 2 rows in a simple `reprex`
below:

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'ggplot2':
# A function that takes a row as a vector
diff_vec <- function(inp_vec, diff_val){
    base::return(inp_vec - diff_val)
}

# Create a test (dummy) dataset with 3 rows and 4 columns
test_dat <- mtcars %>% dplyr::slice(c(1, 3, 6)) %>% dplyr::select(1:4)
test_dat
#>    mpg cyl disp  hp
#> 1 21.0   6  160 110
#> 2 22.8   4  108  93
#> 3 18.1   6  225 105

# This is the vector we want to subtract from each row
diff_v <- c(3.2, 5.4, 7.5, 8.2) 

first_row <- test_dat %>% dplyr::slice(1) %>% as.vector()
test_out1 <- diff_vec(inp_vec = first_row, diff_val = diff_v)
first_row
#>   mpg cyl disp  hp
#> 1  21   6  160 110
test_out1
#>    mpg cyl  disp    hp
#> 1 17.8 0.6 152.5 101.8

second_row <- test_dat %>% dplyr::slice(2) %>% as.vector()
test_out2 = diff_vec(inp_vec = second_row, diff_val = diff_v)
second_row
#>    mpg cyl disp hp
#> 1 22.8   4  108 93
test_out2
#>    mpg  cyl  disp   hp
#> 1 19.6 -1.4 100.5 84.8
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Could anyone please show how to do this using
`purrr` based approach?

Thanks

Comment: Try `test_dat - as.list(diff_v)` and then `split` if needed.

Comment: it will be good if you use vectorized methods: `data.frame(t(t(test_dat)-diff_v))`

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments. The function I apply across rows may get more complicated than this so prefer to have a general solution which allows me flexibility with the function used and ensure it is made explicit. I will go with the tidy solution suggested for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple solution exists:

```r
test_dat %>% map2_dfc(diff_v, ~ .x - .y)
```

Resulting tibble:

```
    mpg    cyl  disp    hp
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  17.8  0.600  152. 102. 
2  19.6 -1.4    100.  84.8
3  14.9  0.600  218.  96.8
```